# How to created auto naming concept

Tags: java, android

Thanks for previous replies,

How to compare String with ListArray, and whenever the string match the array list it automatically includes any integer value and this integer value should incremented whenever the search will begins. is this possible to do.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You want to check whether a given string is defined in an array list? What does 'includes any integer value...' mean?

Comment: This question is not formed.  What you want to do is probably possible, but what you want is not clearly specified.  Do you know what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
public static String find(String value, ArrayList<String> list){
    int count = 1;
    String test = value;
    while(list.contains( test )) {
        test = value+count;
        count++;
    }
    return test;
}
```

test implementation :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add( "test" );
list.add( "test1" );
list.add( "test2" );
System.out.println(find("test", list));
```

output

```
test3
```

Comment: Maybe the method need to return something or have side effect to be interesting.

Comment: right, but i dont know what he want, now i return the next not included string